# Probabillity of a measurement belonging to a certain series

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

We have done a bunch of measurements of air speed in function of pressure drop for different stack configurations. Stack configurations entail:

- the number of films in the stack (known)
- the distance between films (known)
- the orientation of the films with regards to other films in the stack. We don't controll for this variable which causes a a difference between different measurements in a stack.

There is a clear grouping of measurements with similar stack configurations (number of films, distance between films). Within each group there is some variability caused by the uncontrolled inter-film orientation.

An example of 5 measurements with the same number of films (2) and same distance between the films (no distance). Each of the measurements (or setups in the legend of the graph) has a different inter-film orientation.
[image]

However one of our measurements was not labeled we don't know how many films there were in that measurement nor what the distance between films was (if there was more than one film). 
I'm looking for a method to give me a probability that one measurement belongs to a block of measurements with the same number of films and same distance between the films.

The measurement we are talking about is the grey one in the graph below.
[image]

Any and all help to point me in the right direction for the correct statistical tool would be helpful.

EDIT: added the data set: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N8sl-1XpCbC9xM--7NbKOKTbrKng7W5B/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey Dries, so there are 7 different columns in your table separated by colons, but there are only 6 different column names. Could you make it clear which number corresponding to which column name? Thanks

Comment: Strange it should only contain six columns. Anyhow I found a solution using the method below. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem. To estimate the 'probability that one measurement belongs to a block of measurements' requires that you setup your data with a dependent variable that identifies the correct block. Then you can score unknown measurements and get a probability for each unique block that existed.

The downside of this, is that this won't work very well if the choices of what blocks to choose from is constantly changing over time. Is that the case? If so, I'd be leaning more towards a similarity or clustering algorithm rather than treating it as "probability" aka classification.

I think this sounds like something I could ultimately help with, but I'm so unfamiliar w/ this industry and what your data means, that I'd have to learn more. Perhaps you can paste a table of how the data "looks" (fake data, of course) and an example of what you're trying to do in a little more detail.

One idea that came to mind, is that if your measurement always contains multiple samples, enough that you can fit this poly line each time... what you could do is

1) take all existing measurements and iteratively fit your poly line for each

2) store the attributes of that poly line in a dataset

Like this:

```
| measurement_id | fitted_x2_coeff | fitted_x_term | fitted_intercept_term | fit_rsquare | fit_at_q_040 | fit_at_q_060 | fit_at_q_080 | fit_at_q_100 |
|----------------|-----------------|---------------|-----------------------|-------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|              1 |          5476.2 |       -1928.5 |                205.61 |      0.9751 |      310.402 |    -569.9189 |    442.77248 |    -258.5418 |
|              2 |          4269.2 |        -920.6 |                 47248 |      0.9944 |    47562.832 |   28018.3784 |  77802.34752 |   75582.2048 |
|              3 |          3462.5 |       -1076.8 |                 83364 |      0.9962 |     83487.28 |   49631.7482 |   136841.037 |  133120.0244 |
|              4 |          3254.8 |       -1171.8 |                 80881 |      0.9943 |    80933.048 |   48107.7463 |  132697.6834 |  129041.7886 |
|              5 |          6585.6 |         -2475 |                185.22 |      0.9806 |      248.916 |    -778.8874 |    368.24128 |    -528.9908 |
|              6 |          634.63 |         12.13 |                 22886 |      0.9948 |   22992.3928 |   13736.9616 |  37640.22864 |   36730.3492 |
```

(this doesnt look correct but I was just trying to key it in from the screenshots)

*NOTE: an interesting attribute to add would be to fit a fixed point (0.40, 0.60, etc) onto this poly line and get the estimate of that*

IF you think a finite number of clusters exist:

3a) Build a clustering algorithm until you're satisfied about how many clusters there are.

IF you think clusters do not exist:

3b) Build a similarity algorithm such as cosine similarity

4) when you get a new measurement, fit the poly line, and then either assign it the nearest cluster OR print the measurements which the similarity algorithm says is closest

Here is an example of how you could achieve setting up Step 2 in python:

```
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import numpy as np

def dataframe_to_row(df):
    temp = df[['q','pa']].values
    x = temp[:,1]
    y = temp[:,0]

    # note: this is confusing: please refer to ordering of coeffs from this post
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767523/fitting-data-with-numpy
    coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 2)
    fit_040 = poly.polyval([0.4], coefs)
    fit_060 = poly.polyval([0.6], coefs)
    fit_100 = poly.polyval([1.0], coefs)

    return np.concatenate(([m], coefs, fit_040,  fit_060, fit_100))

# create empty dataframe to start
knowns = pd.DataFrame()

# for each measurement, loop and create a new row
measurements = indata.measurement_id.unique()
for m in measurements:
    row = dataframe_to_row(indata[indata['measurement_id']==m])
    knowns = knowns.append(pd.Series(row), ignore_index=True)

knowns.columns=['measurement_id','coef_x0','coef_x1','coef_x2','fit_at_040','fit_at_060','fit_at_100']
```

```
| measurement_id | coef_x0  | coef_x1  |  coef_x2  | fit_at_040 | fit_at_060 | fit_at_100 |
|----------------|----------|----------|-----------|------------|------------|------------|
|              1 | 0.129924 | 0.000715 | -2.14E-07 |    0.13021 |   0.130353 |   0.130639 |
|              2 | 0.145293 | 0.000709 | -2.02E-07 |   0.145577 |   0.145719 |   0.146002 |
|              3 | 0.181559 | 0.000585 | -1.51E-07 |   0.181793 |    0.18191 |   0.182144 |
|              4 | 0.185028 | 0.000628 | -2.05E-07 |    0.18528 |   0.185405 |   0.185656 |
|              5 | 0.130258 | 0.000869 | -3.36E-07 |   0.130606 |    0.13078 |   0.131127 |
|              6 | 0.174058 | 0.000713 | -2.48E-07 |   0.174343 |   0.174486 |   0.174771 |
|              7 | 0.178403 | 0.000881 | -2.69E-07 |   0.178755 |   0.178931 |   0.179283 |
|              8 | 0.240019 | 0.001389 | -3.18E-07 |   0.240574 |   0.240852 |   0.241407 |
|              9 | 0.143386 | 0.000679 | -1.90E-07 |   0.143658 |   0.143793 |   0.144065 |
|             10 | 0.169423 | 0.000585 | -1.48E-07 |   0.169657 |   0.169774 |   0.170008 |
|             11 | 0.165818 | 0.000933 | -3.33E-07 |   0.166191 |   0.166378 |   0.166751 |
```

Comment: Added a potential solution, depending on your circumstances

Comment: Thanks Josh. I've added the data in my original post. I'm going to think about your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @DriesVanEyck is the goal to receive a "new" measurement with the exact same data columns as-is in this sheet? And the goal is to associate it with another measurement that already exists that is similar?

Comment: Exactly we generated a new measurement with the Number of films and the distance between films categories blank. And then we try to allocate these variables based on clustering

Comment: I have used your method to order the data. Then I used a support vector machine to cluster the new data point. For now one the new data point is difficult to place, classify, but this is mainly due to the lack of data points in one of the clusters. I'm going to gather some more datapoints for that cluster, and normally everything will be fine then.

Comment: @DriesVanEyck sounds good. Did you do any clustering before the support vector machine? The vector machine is predicting *something* which if you predict which measurement_id it is, might not work so great. After you get more data, perhaps try clustering with either DBSCAN or K-Means on the dataset above. I'm guessing some measurement_id's will be similar to others and you could group them together.

Comment: I clusterd them manually by the number of films in the the system, so 1 or 2 foils. I tought this was a legitimate strategy because I know this to be true. But I'll try to implement one of those methods too.